# Occasional Ninject error "More than one matching bindings are available."

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, ninject

I have an app that uses Ninject 3.2.2, ninject.mvc5 3.2.1, ninject.web.common 3.2.3 and ninject.web.common.webhost 3.2.0

App normally works without issue, but once in a while it gives an error:

"Error activating IDbFactory
More than one matching bindings are available.
Matching bindings:
 1) binding from IDbFactory to DbFactory
 2) binding from IDbFactory to DbFactory
Activation path:
 4) Injection of dependency IDbFactory into parameter dbFactory of constructor of type OverviewRepository
 3) Injection of dependency IOverviewRepository into parameter repository of constructor of type OverviewService
 2) Injection of dependency IOverviewService into parameter overviewService of constructor of type HomeController
 1) Request for HomeController

Suggestions:
 1) Ensure that you have defined a binding for IDbFactory only once.
"

I am not able to reproduce the problem on my side.

Comment: Could you provide the bindings that you are using?

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be resolved by using the "Named" annotation in your class constructor.  For example I have two UnitsOfWork.

```
public AppsUnitOfWork([Named("AppsWork")] DbContext context) {
        this.context = context;            
} 
public UnitOfWork([Named("UnitWork")]DbContext context) {
        this.context = context;
}
```

My bindings are like this:

```
ninjectKernel.Bind<DbContext>().To<OracleDbContext>().Named("UnitWork");
ninjectKernel.Bind<DbContext>().To<AppsDbContext>().Named("AppsWork");
```